# How to fix failure to load H2O Driverless AI (localhost:12345) on CPU-only system?

Tags: driverless-ai

I am setting up H2O DAI on my Windows computer for experimentation, but the DAI interface fails to load. Is there a way to determine what is causing the failure? Is it a problem with the port?

This is for a small test case so I can explore H2O DAI on my computer. I only have a Windows computer, and so I installed using the recommended process of installing the H2O DAI DEB through Ubuntu 18.04 for WSL.

I started H2O DAI using the code below.

## Run Driverless AI.

sudo -H -u dai /opt/h2oai/dai/run-dai.sh

## Access DAI in browser

localhost:12345

## Access H2O Flow in browser

localhost:54321

Running localhost:12345 should show a login screen for the DAI, but the page says "Failure to load, localhost refused to connect."

However, localhost:54321, which is for H2O Flow, immediately shows the Flow interface.

Comment: there is not enough info here to say much.  what does the dai log file in the log directory say?

Comment: @TomKraljevic Hi Tom, thanks for replying. I am not sure how to open the dai log file as i haven't even been able to see the initial interface with the Evaluation Agreement and the login screen. Perhaps you would know how to access it from the Ubuntu console? Sorry, I also am not fluent in Linux as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the ip on your machine instead of `localhost` (Windows10 may not like using `localhost` as the url).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! For now, I will have to pass on the use of h2o DAI to my colleague. This may solve the issue if it occurs in his machine as well.